# Fast refresh that was introduced in React Native 0.61 doesn't work

Tags: react-native

*(also posted in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27583)*

**Update: a day passed and I started my app again. Didn't change anything since posting the question. Now it works fine. No idea what happened...
From the fact that two people marked this question as useful, I understand that I am not the only one having this problem...**

I am running a very basic 'app' (a single file, a single component) for which the code is attached below, using React native 0.61.

Developing for android, on windows 10 with genymotion.

[Fast Refresh](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/fast-refresh) is turned on, but it doesn't seem to work, for example, when:

1. I am changing the 'Posts' string to 'New Posts'
2. When I remove the posts button

Only the debug menu's "reload" refreshes the app and renders the changes.
Any idea why?

#### Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const App = () => {

  const [resource, setResource] = useState('todos');

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 30 }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 0,
        alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => (setResource('posts'))}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              Posts
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{ width: 20 }} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setResource('todos')}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              Todos
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonText: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 20
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#a8a',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 2
  }
});
```

Comment: Which platform are you using? Android or iOS?

Comment: Android, on windows 10 with genymotion. Should have written that. I will update.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new project with: `react-native init example` ?

Comment: The problem is in a new project, created in the last few days.

Comment: Which node version are you using @Yossi?

Comment: @FreakyCoder: v10.16.3
I see that it has been installed some time (maybe long time) ago. 
I just ran my app again with the current versions and it seems to refresh as expected. I haven't changed anything... Strange.

Do you know that a non-recent node version may cause problems?

Answer (score 2):

I've found that sometimes the Metro Bundler gets 'stuck'.  That would explain why when you ran it the next day, it worked fine.

When things get weird for (seemingly) no apparent reason, I do:

`yarn start --reset-cache`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Cannot test it, since I don't have the problem now...

Comment: anyone? something?

Comment: I have tried, to no avail, even cleaned node_modules and reinstall everything as well as `watchman watch-del-all` and/or reinstalling watchman, delete .git/index.lock, remove all .lock files from the project. Whenever I change any code, I have to --reset-cache and re-install to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

In my case I ran `watchman watch-del-all` and suddenly I lost fast reload.

Re-installing `node_modules` and clear & rebuilding app did not help me.

> Update: a day passed and I started my app again. Didn't change anything since posting the question. Now it works fine. No idea what happened...

Got a hint from this and restarted my computer. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue few minutes back. Fast refresh was not working even though it was enabled. I closed the metro bundle and started the new instance. Worked for me.