# React-native Fast Refresh broken

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler, watchman

recently my Fast Refresh stopped working across ALL of my react native projects, I have even tried init-ing a new project and it is not working there too

I have tried all the attempts below:

```
-. watchman watch-del-all
-. rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman && brew uninstall watchman && brew install watchman
-. clean node_modules and "npm run -- --reset-cache"
```

Whatever way I try to reload the app after modifying the source code, the change will not get reflected. I have to stop and uninstall the app, run `npm run -- --reset-cache` and then run `npm run android` again in order to have the changes reflected.

This is really killing me as I can not find the cause of it. It was working before and I did not install any app on my machine. I am now short of formatting my machine and start everything from scratch again but this is a Mac and it is troublesome to reformat..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried ALL the solutions mentioned here? Seems like there're still a bunch that you haven't tried

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28420

I tried almost all and still not working, in desperation, the

`sudo npx react-native start` solved my problem

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28420#issuecomment-755082770

Comment: lifesaver!! only thing that worked was this! I can confirm as of 2024

Answer (score 8):

It's not related to react-native, metro bundler, or sudo permission,
It's because of .git/index.lock file!

Just remove it and everything would be OK.

Execute this command in the root directory of your project:

```
rm .git/index.lock
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the question, but I'm leaving it for people who come here with a slightly different issue.

If after making a code edit, the app shows a message saying 'Refreshing...' but it fully reloads the app, then that means Fast Refresh and Hot Reloading is technically working. But for whatever reason, Fast Refresh is falling back to a full reload. To fix this, [see this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63788454/fast-refresh-in-react-native-always-fully-reload-the-app) Basically, name your default exports.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the changes weren't reflected because I had the `CI` environment variable set.

The Metro bundler is configured to turn off the watch mode in a CI environment.
So check if your environment is considered the CI one. You can do this by running

```js
node -p "require('ci-info')"
```

This command will output a bunch of variables. You are interested in the `isCI` variable. If it is `true`, then check your environment variables and make sure you have removed the CI ones

```js
...
  XCODE_CLOUD: false,
  XCODE_SERVER: false,
  isCI: true
```

For more information see this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/982)